# How to set background color for row with dynamic jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am new to jasper, i know its a basic question. I spent lot of time to get a solution for this , but didn't get a solution for this so far.

I am working a module where i have to generate report by using jasper.I implemented code for pdf generation. We are generating this report using dynamic-jasper api . I used "import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.Style" class to create styles for the report. And i set background value for this styles as follows

**style.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);**

But this is not reflecting, still i am getting the background as white.

Please let me know if i miss something

Kind Regards
Ajil

Answer (score 6):

I goth the solution for this issue. 
I set the transparent attribute as false of style instance. This resolved my issue.